# Average of multiple column with no data involved

Tags: mysql

I have this data from the table `score` below:

```
No   !  id   !  A      !  B    ! average  !
------------------------------------------
1    !  01   !  80     !  60   !    70    !
2    !  02   !         !  60   !    30    !
3    !  03   !  0      !  60   !    30    !
4    !  04   !  80     !       !    40    !
```

I want to get the average of column A and B. using code below:

```
Select id, (avg(A)+avg(B))/2 as Average
from score
Group by id;
```

the problem is, `id 02` and `id 04` have only one data. The average will count it as `0` instead of no data.

table that I want is like this
I have this data from the table `score` below:

```
No   !  id   !  A      !  B    ! average  !
------------------------------------------
1    !  01   !  80     !  60   !    70    !
2    !  02   !         !  60   !    60    !
3    !  03   !  0      !  60   !    30    !
4    !  04   !  80     !       !    80    !
```

anybody can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT id, (SUM(COALESCE(A,0)) + SUM(COALESCE(B,0))) / (COUNT(A) + COUNT(B))
FROM score
GROUP by id
```

The trick here is to compute the average in pieces, by taking the `SUM` divided by the `COUNT`, and using `COALESCE()` appropriately to handle `NULL` values.  Keep in mind that the MySQL aggregate functions (`SUM`, `COUNT`, etc.) *ignore* `NULL` values by default.

I tested the query and you can add additional columns beyond `A` and `B` and it still seems to be working.

**Demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: great:)) it works..one more question, how can i call it with php?  $sql="SELECT id, (SUM(COALESCE(A,0)) + SUM(COALESCE(B,0))) / (COUNT(A) + COUNT(B))
FROM score
GROUP by id"; $result_arraysql=mysql_query($querysql);
$linesql = mysql_fetch_array($result_arraysql); when i call with <?php echo $myData['lineled7apehh']; ?> it shows nothing

Comment: @gtviga This would require a long answer, certainly too long to fit in a comment.  You might want to ask a new question, referencing this one.  I'm sure you will get a fast answer for how to call this with PHP.  You could also read through some tutorials to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have floating-point averages in an integer field.  Unfortunately, averaging will give integer results, so an average of, say, 0 and 1 will be 0.  That having been said, your "average" is guaranteed to be at least as large as the **MIN()** value in the column, and no larger than the **MAX()** value in the column.  If you will want floating-point numbers to be reported in the same column as integers, then don't make it an integer column!